# Jmeter how to send request forever with delay?

Tags: loops, testing, timer, request, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.11

I have a "counter" it include 1 to 1000 userId

And i send :
Number of threads = 1
Ramp-up perioid = 1
Loop = Forever

but "Loop" is not waiting 1 requst per second, it send all at once!

I added "Constant Timer" but it is not effect true delay so:

When i set "Constant Timer = 1000" it effect "request delay time" + "Constant Timer" so its greater then 1 second!

So i just want send 1 request per 1 second with forever loop? (i dont want request legancy)

What should my Jmeter hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a constant throughput to the thread.
Here is the [info](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

It set samples per minute so in your case if you want 1 sample per second, would be 60 samples per minute. hope this fix your problem.